# How to make NERDTree always open on the right side?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

NERDTreeToggle always makes it show up on the left side. I'd like to make it show up on the right. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
```

Comment: where am I supposed to find documentation for these kinds of configuration? E.g. how to make it smaller?

Comment: @LouisRhys You can find the customization documentation here: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/4.2.0/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L592

Comment: and any idea how to print the current value? e..g my current g:NERDTreeWinPos ?

Comment: @LouisRhys `:echo g:NERDTreeWinPos`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the window position in your NERD_Tree.vim file too. I usually like looking through .vim files, if only to help keep my .vimrc file clear.

Here is the code to change:

```
call s:initVariable("g:NERDTreeWinPos", "left") "default
call s:initVariable("g:NERDTreeWinPos", "right")
```

The code should be at line number 90, if not then I have included the default so that you can search for it.

Also, here is a [link](http://media.kbct.de/home/vim/doc/NERD_tree) for some info on the NERD_Tree.vim file.

Comment: I understand the need to keep things clean, but you should keep in mind that you can't track of you configurations changing several different files and, if you get some of your plugins directly from repositories, you will have to reconfig every time you update the plugin. Just saying ;)

Answer (score 1):

I Open NERDTree at right window with this.

```
$ vim ~/.vimrc
...

let NERDTreeWinPos=1
```